# Message Sent to Deallocated Instance when adding storyboard view as a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

Okay, I have a basic understanding of what is happening here, but am having trouble fixing it. I am hoping someone can walk me through what I'm doing wrong here...

I have a nifty app that works great and was built with the storyboard and custom UIViewControllers to handle all my code. I was doing really well, until I needed to handle my push notifications by dropping me in a specific view and loading some data. I made a lot of headway today and just got stuck in a bad way. I am now getting an objc_sendmsg error and I know it has to do with my memory management. I've never initialized a view in this way, so I'm wondering if that's what's causing it. Basically, I can load a view, but I can never push any buttons or get anywhere after that.

Here's the code:

AppDelegate.m

```
    UIStoryboard* storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *detailVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Leads_Calls_SB"];
    [self.window addSubview:detailVC.view];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"callReceived"
                                                            object:nil
                                                          userInfo:userInfo];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Leads_CallsDetailViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cStart;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cNumber;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cStart2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cEnd;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cDuration;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cStatus;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cProvider;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cLineType;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cCity;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *innerView;
@property (strong, nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *backStyle;


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@property (strong, nonatomic, retain) NSString *cNotifID;

@property (strong, nonatomic, retain) NSString *cNameText;
@property (strong, nonatomic, retain) NSString *cNumberText;
@property (strong, nonatomic, retain) NSString *cStartText;
@property (strong, nonatomic, retain) NSString *cEndText;
@property (strong, nonatomic, retain) NSString *cCallStatusText;
@property (strong, nonatomic, retain) NSString *cLatitudeText;
@property (strong, nonatomic, retain) NSString *cLongitudeText;
@property (strong, nonatomic, retain) NSString *cCityText;
@property (strong, nonatomic, retain) NSString *cLineTypeText;
@property (strong, nonatomic, retain) NSString *cProviderNameText;
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *map;

- (IBAction)forward_lead:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)call_lead:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)add_lead:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *bottomMessage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *bottomCalls;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *bottomReports;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *bottomHome;
```

.m

```
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    if (self.cNotifID != nil)
    {
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    else {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but no matter what happens if I hit any button on that page or try to dismiss the view, it screams at me and gets angry...I've tried everything I can think of to figure this out.

Thanks guys!

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: *** -[Leads_CallsDetailViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1d8693f0

Comment: Is there anyway to get more information than that?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you're creating your view controller, grabbing its view, but the letting the controller fall out of scope (and presumably using ARC where it's getting released on you).

In my original answer, I thought the goal was simply to consider different ways of presenting the standard initial view controller. But that is not the case. The question is how to present a new scene when some event takes place (in my example, I'm doing it upon [`openURL`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3aopenURL%3asourceApplication%3aannotation%3a), but you could presumably do this in response to notifications and the like).

Anyway, one approach to solving this is to perform `presentViewController`. So you could do something like:

```
// determine the current controller (in case you've already done some modal segues)

UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UIViewController *currentController = window.rootViewController;
while (currentController.presentedViewController)
    currentController = currentController.presentedViewController;

// load the controller for the new scene

UIStoryboard* storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *newController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Leads_Calls_SB"];

// perform a modal transition to the new scene

[currentController presentViewController:newController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: 1 more question. Whenever I try the presentViewController, I just get a black screen and it seems impossible to debug...any tips on that? I changed the addSubview line to this: UIViewController *presentingController = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
            [presentingController presentViewController:detailVC animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: My comment about `presentViewController` was before I noticed you were doing this from your app delegate. So, instead, create a new, sample non-storyboard project and look what it does in the app delegate and model your app delegate upon that (define a `UIWindow` property and set its `rootViewController`, or, better, use the "Main Storyboard" setting in your target settings and you don't have to do anything in your app delegate.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for your help. I'm starting to kind of understand the presentation of the views. My MainStoryboard is defined in the target settings, but I'm still not sure why presenting the view from the appdelegate results in a black screen...any other ideas what might cause that?

Comment: @ChrisJenkins If you define the "Main Storyboard", then your app delegate doesn't need to do anything special, as iOS will automatically load the initial scene for you, and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` doesn't have to do any of this silliness. But if you want to load it manually, leave "Main Storyboard" blank and then you'll have to do something like I've outlined in my revised answer. Why not let the "Main Storyboard" do it's thing, and don't do any messing around with windows, controllers, views or anything, in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

Comment: Sorry, I must not have made myself clear. The whole app works perfectly, I'm just trying to present the proper view when I'm receiving a notification. All of this runs under didReceiveRemoteNotification, and I keep running into 1 of 2 issues. Either I can make it pop up with info and can't click anything, or my view just doesn't show up. The subview got me to the view and I was able to program my view for notifications, but from there it crashes every button push. If I do a presentViewController from a window, it just shows a black screen on me :/

Comment: @ChrisJenkins Ok, I misunderstood the question. If you want to present another view upon some event, you can identify the currently presented view controller and do a `presentViewController` from there, as I've outlined above.

Comment: I must have broken something else. I really appreciate your help, but I have no idea why I get a black screen when doing this, but adding a subview to a new window works (kind of). I stepped through all of this code and all the values seem fine and then on presentViewController, it just goes black. Thanks so much...I would be lost without help.